# Static NAT doesn't work

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, cisco-commands

I'm trying to let computer from Internet to get access to the external DMZ(Server Mail and Server FTP) so I translated the address of the internet network like :

```
ip nat inside source static 172.16.1.4 209.165.201.1 
ip nat inside source static 172.16.1.3 209.165.201.2
```

but it doesn't work, i always got :

Reply from 200.14.5.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 200.14.5.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 200.14.5.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 200.14.5.1: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 209.165.201.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outside interface will block anything destined for your server addresses. The ACL on that interface only specifically allows traffic to hosts `199.14.5.1`, `199.14.5.10`, and `199.14.5.11`.

Remember, an ACL will have an implicit `deny all` at the end, so you are denying all other inbound traffic.

Comment: So i should add permission access-list 101 permit ip any host 209.165.201.1 and access-list 101 permit ip any host 209.165.201.2 ?

Comment: If you want to be able to access the servers from the outside, you will need to permit traffic destined to the `209.165.201.1` and `209.165.201.2` addresses to enter the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a permit any on your standard list and if you need more granular information then use an extended list four specific ports.

Comment: I just add these 2 and and it worked  access-list 101 permit ip any host 209.165.201.1 and access-list 101 permit ip any host 209.165.201.2